# No Block production with multiple nodes / AURA

Tags: block-production, aura, finalization, block-size

I have a solo-chain with PoA consensus, `MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK` of `1000`, 5MB of `MAX_BLOCK_SIZE`, and 400ms of `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT`. The chain produces and finalizes blocks when there's a single authoring node, but as soon as, I attempt to run multiple nodes after adding them in the `chain_spec.rs`, the blocks are produced but not finalized, and I get this error: `Failed to handle sync state from PeerId("12D3KooWE6AEVHZVzr9KvkaAQftnu9wwU6QLgdrF5XVs4Tx9vydX")`, and if I would try to add validators through the Polkadot UI, there's no such error neither there's any block production from the second node. I've tried changing the block production times, but it didn't solve the issue.

Note: The consensus is using `Aura` for block production, and `DAGs` for rapid finality, inspired from [AlephZero](https://docs.alephzero.org/aleph-zero/explore/alephbft-consensus#:%7E:text=using%20DAGs%20allows%20for%20faster%20transaction%20speeds%20and%20higher%20throughput%20and%20hence%20significantly%20lower%20transaction%20fees.) with some modifications of Account types.